# Subclass activity for testing

Tags: java, android, testing, android-activity

For the instrumented testing of my Android app, I've subclassed my `Application` class and created a runner subclass to make sure that it gets used.  So far, so good.  However, I now need to subclass one of my activities during testing to do some setup before `onCreate` is called:

```java
class TestActivity extends MyActivity {
    @Override
    protected void
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // do some setup

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

The problem is I get the error

> Unable to resolve activity for: Intent  { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.myapp/.activities.TestActivity (has extras) }

I had the idea of creating an AndroidManifest.xml under `app/src/androidTest`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:name=".application.TestApplication">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TestActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Show Download" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and editing my build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

However, after syncing and re-running the test, I get the same error.

Is there a way to register an `Activity` class just for testing?

EDIT:

I realize this is a classic XY problem and I've since refactored my code to not need this.  However, the curiosity remains.